# SQL Statement to update multiple columns with multiple where conditions

Tags: html, ruby, postgresql, sinatra, pgadmin

So I have the following SQL statement:

```
db.exec("UPDATE products SET product_description = '#{fj_description}' AND personalization = '#{fj_personalization}' AND product_photo = '#{fj_product_photo}' AND order_information = '#{fj_order_information}' WHERE campaign_name = '#{camp_name}' AND product_type = 'fleecejacket'")
```

All of the variables are returning the correct text that's retrieved from an HTML input field, so it seems to be something wrong with the sql statement. When I try to update the database, I get this error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation at /update_products
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "soft, midweight fleece" LINE 1: UPDATE products SET product_description = 'soft, midweight f... ^
```

Comment: As the documentation states, UPDATE does not use AND between values. `SET some=1, other=2, third=3...`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen that works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Please please please do not do this in such a manner what would you do if i placed this in the *"HTML input field"* for fj_description   `"'; DELETE FROM products;--`

Comment: @engineersmnky the only people able to access the page that you can do that are administrators. It is not reachable by a customer.

Comment: @athill16 that should not matter security is not to protect from customers it is to protect the data. Maybe an administrator is having a bad day or maybe he doesn't know SQL and some one asks for their personalization to read "MY Names'; DROP TABLE products--" **NEVER TRUST USER INPUT** regardless of the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using comma instead `AND`:

```
"UPDATE products 
 SET product_description = '#{fj_description}',
   personalization = '#{fj_personalization}',
   product_photo = '#{fj_product_photo}',
   order_information = '#{fj_order_information}' 
 WHERE campaign_name = '#{camp_name}' 
 AND product_type = 'fleecejacket'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the "AND's" to commas without changing the quotes and it was all I needed to fix it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify it, thanks @athill16.